# Qt 5.5 drawing a pointer

Tags: rotation, polygon, qt5.5

Is there a built in method for drawing an arrow/pointer at the end of a line in Qt?

I know I can draw it myself, but curious to know if there is already a way of doing this, I've search online and couldn't find anything.

I want to be able to rotate the line and the arrow rotates with it.

Below is the image I'm working on:

[image]

I would like to draw the arrow at the end of the dashed line, it should rotate with the dash line pointing around from the bottom left.

[edit] In the end I used a polygon and rotated that:

[image]

Code to add polygon needle:

```
    Polygon clsMyClass::plygnGetNeedle(QPoint* pptOrigin
                                      ,int intRadius
                                      ,float fltAngle) {
        const int cintNeedleHalfWidth = 4;

        QPolygon plyNeedle;
        int intX = pptOrigin->x(), intY = pptOrigin->y();
        plyNeedle << QPoint(intX - cintNeedleHalfWidth, intY)
                  << QPoint(intX, intY + cintNeedleHalfWidth)
                  << QPoint(intX + intRadius - cintNeedleHalfWidth, intY)
                  << QPoint(intX, intY- cintNeedleHalfWidth);
        return QTransform().translate(intX, intY)
                           .rotate(fltAngle)
                           .translate(-intX, -intY)
                           .map(plyNeedle);
    }
```

Comment: "I've search online and couldn't find anything." That's because they really keep the nice features hidden ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall something like this in Qt. As for the position and angle of the arrow - you can easily find those out if you use something like `QPainterPath`'s `angleAtPercent()` and `pointAtPercent()` functions.

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate, atm, drawing the arrow with QPolygon

Comment: I have now drawn the arrow using QPolygon and QPainterPath, now can I easily attach the polygon to a line without having to work-out all the points and then rotate it with the line?

Comment: @SPlatten - you can simply transform the painter itself, instead of rotating the line and arrow simply rotate the painter

Comment: But doesn't that rotate everything on the Painter?  I want the background to remain static and only the polygon and pointer to rotate.

Comment: No, only the painter is rotated, it is not the same as transforming the "canvas". For example, if you want to mirror a drawing, first you draw everything, then you rotate the painter 180 degree then execute the draw code again. This way you get the result without modifying the points.

Comment: Ok, I'm with you :)...but...I want the polygon rotation to be based on one specific co-ordinate, for example if the polygon represents a meter needle, how to rotate the needle based on the lower left co-ordinate?